# iOS: How to disable bounces effect in tableview?

Tags: ios

I have a simple tabelviewcontroller and I want to remove/disable the bouncing effect (e.g. used when pull-to-refresh).

I have tried to set refreshControl to null but I get an exception (argument cannot be null).

I am using Xamarin but my question is not specific to Xamarin.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012250-CH1-SW4

Comment: @Nick, the docs explain how to use UIRefreshControl. I want to disable it. There is no mention of this in the doc.

Comment: I assumed you meant stop refreshing, however that is not the case, so why do you want to disable it? Why don't you just NOT implement it into the table view?

Comment: @Nick, I presume it's default behavior. I didn't implement it.

Comment: It must be different in Xamarin then, as in Xcode/Objective-C you need to implement UIRefreshControl.

Answer (score 4):

I found out myself. I feel slightly stupid but for future reference:
If you need to disable the pull-to-refresh / bounce effect then just uncheck "bounces" property on the scroll view in the storyboard.

Comment: The bounce has nothing to do with Refresh - it is purely aesthetic ! 
Pull to refresh is enabled and used entirely differently then what this question tries to portray !

Comment: @TaskinulHaque Changed question to make that more clear.